# nHibernate 2.1: Save a new entity in a for

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Well, this is driving me crazy, I cannot understand why is this happening.
I have a method for saving a list of JobExperiences and a JobExperience has a relation to a Company. The problem comes that I-m trying to create a new Company inside the foreach and save it, but nHibernate is trying to save the JobExperience also ... and it is not referenced to the JobExperience!. 
Here is my code:

```
 foreach (JobExperience exp in expList)
 {
    if (exp.Company.IsNew)
    {
        try
        {
            Company c = new Company();
            c.Name = "CompanyTest";

            companyService.Save(c); //throws an exception!
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 

        }
    }
```

So, at that line is trying to save the JobExperience and it is showing an exception cause it is a non saved one. But, if I try this:

```
try
{
    Company c = new Company();
    c.Name = "CompanyTest";

    companyService.Save(c);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}

foreach (JobExperience exp in expList)
{
//[... code excluded for abbreviation ]
```

That works!, and it is not trying to save any JobExperience!....

Any thoughts why is this happening?

Comment: Can you please post the mappings you have for these entities ??

Comment: Can you also post the exception message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the relationship between is currently mandatory, and you have two basic choices:
1) if in your system, it is possible to have JobExperience without a Company, you can just change the relationship mapping to be optional by saying not-null="true in your hbm (or the equivalent in some fluent mapping tool if you are using one).
2) if the relationship should be mandatory, you should save a company first.

HTH,
Berryl

Comment: Exactly Berry, I had a mess with my config xml. I'm new on  nHibernate, and it was the first of your options. I study a little more from there and now it is working. Thanks!